# serve_file for any file object

Tags: cherrypy

In cherrypy.lib.static.py there is a method:

```
  serve_file(path, content_type=None, disposition=None, name=None)
```

where the argument "path" must be a real file (absolute path). Is there something similar to serve any Python file object?

Comment: The serve_fileobj function works perfectly for this.  (It would be helpful for the community if you would accept the correct answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From studying http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/trunk/cherrypy/lib/static.py I'd have to say, no: the `serve_file` function is "monolithic", and does its own `bodyfile = open(path, 'rb')`, nor does there seem to be any alternative way. Pity, as it would be easy to refactor the function and add another e.g. `serve_open_file` to cover your case, having both delegate to an internal function for the "hard" logic such as multipart/byteranges serving. May be worth your while to open a feature request ("enhancement ticket") on cherrypy.org -- may not be a killer feature but I can see use cases, and implementing it wouldn't be hard for the cherrypy people (visit [their site](http://www.cherrypy.org/newticket) and follow the instructions on the page to "log in" to it).

Comment: If I understand correctly, I think this answer is no longer true, with the addition of the `serve_fileobj` method.

Comment: Yes, serve_filobj does exactly what OP wants.  (This answer is out of date.)

Answer (score 2):

As long as your file or file-like object is iterable, just return it from your handler function instead of a string.

**Update:**

To serve it as a download, set the Content-Type and Content-Disposition headers like so:

```
cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-download"
cd = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % name
cherrypy.response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = cd
```

Or, use the `serve_fileobj` function in recent versions of `cherrypy/lib/static.py`, which does this for you and more.

Comment: This works if you want to render the file contents on the screen. Is there a way to allow the file to be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a new look at http://www.cherrypy.org/browser/trunk/cherrypy/lib/static.py, it looks like `serve_fileobj` does exactly what you want.

Edit: I've tried this now, and it only renders the file contents to the screen, rather than allowing the file to be downloaded.